# Calculating accumulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, power-towers

I would firstly like to point out that I am just becoming very interested in maths but have very little technical mathematical knowledge, so I, therefore, understand that the phenomenon that I'm talking about might not be called "accumulation", but I would be equally interested to hear what it's called.

There is a challenge where a person saves money. On day one they save one cent and every subsequent day they save the same amount as yesterday plus 1 cent. For example:

```
Day Number   Addition   Saving  Total Savings 
(x)                             (y)
---------------------------------------------------

1            £0.01      £0.01   £0.01
2            £0.01      £0.02   £0.03
3            £0.01      £0.03   £0.06
4            £0.01      £0.04   £0.10
5            £0.01      £0.05   £0.15
6            £0.01      £0.06   £0.21
7            £0.01      £0.07   £0.28
8            £0.01      £0.08   £0.36
9            £0.01      £0.09   £0.45
10           £0.01      £0.10   £0.55
```

I am looking to create an equation to find the value of y (the total value of savings) for any given day number.

I know that essentially the calculation is:

```
(Day Number × 1 Cent) + (((Day Number)-1) × 1 cent))...
```

continued until day number is equal to 1

My question is: Is there a simple way to show to do this as an equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us denote the current savings by $a_n$ for the $n^{th}$ day, in pennies to make things simpler. Then we see that

> $$a_n = a_{n-1} + n$$

because we start with $a_{n-1}$ in the savings, and add $n$ pennies (because on the given day we add one more penny than the previous and start at $1$ on day one). We have the initial condition that $a_1=1$ (we start with one penny saved on day one).

This defines a recurrence relation, where we can express future terms in a sequence by referring to the previous ones. This in particular is a "nonhomogenous" (we have some terms that do not reference previous terms), "linear" (each term refers to at most one previous term) recurrence relation.

This is a simple one and can be solved explicitly if you want a general form, one that does not rely on reference to previous terms (where you can just plug in $n$ and figure out what you have on day $n$). There are plenty of methods to solve this, but they might fly a little above your head. So I'll discuss the longer if more intuitive way to solve this.

Imagine iterating this recurrence relation backwards. The recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1} + n$ holds for any $n \ge 1$. So we also know that $a_{n-1} = a_{n-2} + (n-1)$ for $n$ large enough, for example. Let's use this fact and iterate back a few times...

$$\begin{align}
a_n &= a_{n-1} + n\\
&= a_{n-2} + (n-1) + n\\
&= a_{n-3} + (n-2) + (n-1) + n\\
&= a_{n-4} + (n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n\\
\end{align}$$

A pattern emerges! After $k$ back-iterations in this vein, we see

$$\begin{align}
a_n &= a_{n-k} + (n-k+1) + (n-k+2) + (n-k+3) + \cdots + (n-1) + n \\
&= a_{n-k} + \sum_{i=1}^k (n-k+i)
\end{align}$$

What happens if $k=n-1$? Then we can use our initial condition, as

$$a_n = a_{1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-(n-1)+i) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (i+1)$$

What is that summation? If you write it out, we clearly see

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (i+1) = 2+3+4+\cdots+(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n$$

Why, this is almost like the sum of the first $n$ integers, aside from missing $1$, but our initial condition gives us that! Thus we can claim,

> $$a_n = \text{(the sum of the first n integers)} = \sum_{i=1}^n i$$

(Arguably one could start at the above fact just by common sense - "I add one on day one, two on day two, three on day three, and so on, and I start with nothing.") Okay, but what is this sum? This is a common introductory proof by induction, but essentially we obtain

> $$a_n = \frac{n(n+1)} 2$$

If you wish to see the details behind the proof, a search on MSE for "sum of the first $n$ integers" should bring up plenty of results.

Notably, one with good pattern recognition skills might recognize your "total savings" values, and realize the above is the solution right off, because $1,3,6,10,15,\cdots$ form a sequence of "triangular numbers," which are defined by this recurrence relation and have the general form highlighted above. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) has an article on them.

To then convert this into pounds, bear in mind that we have found the total number of pennies saved, so we can just divide by $100$. Accordingly, if $y(n)$ denotes the savings on day $n$, then

> $$y(n) = \frac{a_n}{100} = \frac{n(n+1)}{200}$$